# Android, Getting an error, Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. > Manifest merger failed, when trying to integrate Helpshift plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, helpshift

I'm getting this error with my code when I try and implement a plugin called Helpshift.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.>
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute
>   meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from
>   AndroidManifest.xml:16:13-35      is also present at
>   [com.android.support:design:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>   value=(26.1.0).       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to
>    element at AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-16:38 to override.

I think it has something to do with the versions of the app.
Here's my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.leoconnelly.connexus">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="26" android:compileSDKVersion="26" android:buildToolsVersion="26" />
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".HealthCenterListActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".HealthCenterSelectedActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MoreInfoActivity" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.0.1" />

</application>
```

and here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.leoconnelly.connexus"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}



dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

//Helpshift
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.helpshift:android-helpshift-en-aar:6.4.2'



}
```

I beleive I'm doing something wrong with the versions, but when I change them I get a whole other error. Any help is apperciated.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line in the manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="26"  android:compileSDKVersion="26" android:buildToolsVersion="26" />
```

and in  your build.gradle add this line in defaultConfig section:

```
  buildToolsVersion '26.1.0'
```

do what  @prem   said above

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
```

Instead of this

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the support library is a hard dependency in Helpshift sdk, you can exclude it and using your selected support library version with something like this:

```
//Helpshift
// use version 26.1.0 instead of 26.0.2
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

// exclude the support library
implementation ('com.helpshift:android-helpshift-en-aar:6.4.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'design'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview'
    exclude module: 'cardview-v7'
}
```